# Is there a way to report which SQL Server stored procedures or functions have errors?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to report on SQL Server stored procedures and functions that have errors?

For example:

```
-- THERE IS NO SUCH TABLE AS BAZ
CREATE PROCEDURE FOO AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM BAZ
END
```

The above statement executes correctly. But later, it gets compiled before execution...

```
exec foo
```

which yields...

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure foo, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 5]
>   Invalid object name 'BAZ'.

I have tried invoking the compile directly...

```
exec sp_recompile 'dbo.foo'
```

Which sadly yields...

```
Object 'dbo.foo' was successfully marked for recompilation.
```

So it seems the only to trigger it is to execute it, like...

```
USE JOSHUA

EXEC PLAY_GLOBAL_THERMONUCLEAR_WAR

-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXzNo0vR_dU
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can write a query that will do this. You need to leverage [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-expression-dependencies-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). Something like this will get you the information you are looking for.

```
select MyObjectName = object_name(referencing_id)
    , MyObjectType = so.type_desc
    , MissingReferenceName = referenced_entity_name
    , MissingReferenceType = referenced_class_desc
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
join sys.objects so on so.object_id = d.referencing_id
where OBJECT_ID(referenced_entity_name) IS NULL
order by MyObjectName
    , MissingReferenceName
```

Comment: 'you guys' never cease to amaze me :)